# How to remove just one element from arraylist while iterating over it

Tags: java

I wanted to remove single element which matches orderID = 542 .But the thing is this program is removing two elements from that list.In the real program i m iterating through an arraylist and i call a function to check whether that element is to be removed from the list and that function is suppose to remove the element from the list

```
package testMap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestHashMap {
    static ArrayList<LimitOrder> a = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        create();
    }

    public static void create() {
        LimitOrder l1 = new LimitOrder(1, 100, "145");

        LimitOrder l2 = new LimitOrder(1, 100, "542");

        LimitOrder l3 = new LimitOrder(1, 100, "355");

        a.add(0, l1);
        a.add(1, l2);
        a.add(2, l3);

        Iterator<LimitOrder> i = a.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            boolean toremove = false;
            LimitOrder l = i.next();
            toremove=remove();
            if (toremove == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Removed "+l.orderID);
                i.remove();
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean remove() {
        boolean flag = false;
        Iterator<LimitOrder> i = a.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            LimitOrder l = i.next();
            if (l.orderID.equals("542")) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;

    }

}
```

Please help me

Comment: Can you not put the condition to check id in the first while loop itself? I mean, you may not required remove() method at all.

Comment: In the remove() method, if it meets the condition, break out of the loop after setting the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing elements from the list that do not match.  And that is happening because your test to decide if an element should be removed is wrong.  You should be testing if *this* element matches ... not if *any* element matches.

The fix is to change the test to test just the current element; e.g.

```
    ...
    Iterator<LimitOrder> i = a.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        LimitOrder l = i.next();
        if (isMatch(l)) {
            i.remove();
            System.out.println("Removed " + l.orderID);
        }
    }
    ...

public static boolean isMatch(LimitOrder l) {
    return l.orderID.equals("542");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to have an iterator in the `remove` method, you can pass the current `LimitOrder` from the `create` method.

```
static ArrayList<LimitOrder> a = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    create();
}

public static void create() {
    LimitOrder l1 = new LimitOrder(1, 100, "145");

    LimitOrder l2 = new LimitOrder(1, 100, "542");

    LimitOrder l3 = new LimitOrder(1, 100, "355");

    a.add(0, l1);
    a.add(1, l2);
    a.add(2, l3);

    Iterator<LimitOrder> i = a.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        LimitOrder l = i.next();
        if (remove(l))
        {
            System.out.println("Removed "+l.orderID);
            i.remove();
        }
    }

}

public static boolean remove(LimitOrder l) {
    if (l.orderID.equals("542")) {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not like that...the second function is suppose to decide if the element is to be removed or not...

Answer (score 0):

Update your function remove() to receive and check current iterator value.

Comment: can u please tel me how to do that?

Comment: Please, see @Arun's example